# Where the production run data is saved in the database of apache ofbiz

Tags: apache, erp, ofbiz

Does someone know where the manufacturing production run data is saved in database of Apache ofbiz. I need to find out the current routing task, when the production run is started.
Can someone guide me to find out the data of production run.

Thank you.

Comment: For a better experience ask such questions in the user ml of the Apache OFBiz project. Best regards, Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the production run and its tasks are saved in the entity named WorkEffort (i.e. database table WORK_EFFORT); different values in the workEffortTypeId field are used for production runs and the tasks.